# Build custom Geo Maps d3js

Tags: d3.js

I've a collection of data about my city. In this data I've GEOJson info about neighborhoods and others part of my city. I would build a geo-chart about this with d3js. Is there a tutorial to build a custom map ?
Thanks

Comment: You're question is pretty open ended.  What did you specifically have in mind?  Some good starting palces would be this [post](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/) by Mike Bostock or [this one](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/a-simple-d3js-map-explained.html) by d3 Noob.  Also, Scott Murray's [book](http://alignedleft.com/work/d3-book) is another good starting point.

Comment: I've read Mike Bostock's post and it's very helpfully. But I can't understand how build my map about my city. My dataset contains only information about particular point of city or about neighborhood. Where is can find date to build a custom map like in the example?

Comment: It would depend on where you are, what level of detail etc.  You can usually get high resolution geographic datasets from census organisation or there are a number of different free datasets for countries of the world. Or of course you could use mapping libraries like [leaflet](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/) or [google](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/899711) maps. Here area another couple of examples; [example 1](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7189721) of mapping with d3; and [example 2](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/10447085)

Comment: Well, perfctly. In [example 1](http://bl.ocks.org/phil-pedruco/7189721) os used this [file](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/raw/4090846/us.json) to draw map. Where can I find this kind of file for italy? Can I use leaflet or google maps or openstreemap?